# Google Sitemap Limits?

Tags: google, sitemap

I've read in multiple places that Google's sitemap limits sits at 50,000 URLs per sitemap - though it's my understanding that you can submit multiple sitemaps to overcome this problem.

I've also found that [Google follow the sitemap protocol](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) found [here](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html).

My question is - is there anywhere where Google directly comment on the specifications and limits of sitemaps they accept? All the information I've found isn't behind any Google domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is at [Creating Sitemaps](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183668#1)(via your first link):

> A Sitemap file can contain no more than 50,000 URLs and must be no larger than 50MB when uncompressed. If your Sitemap is larger than this, break it into several smaller Sitemaps.

...among a bunch of other stuff, but that covers your example above.